# Bind change event to checkbox in each DataTables row

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox, datatables

I have added a checkbox for each row in `DataTables`. When table data is loaded, I bind change event to each checkbox like this:

```
fnInitComplete: function(oSettings, json) {

      $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {

            // checking if any checkbox is checked

      });
}
```

The problem is that change event is added only for the first page. If I navigate to other pages and click on any checkbox, no event is fired. It works only if I refresh the page. Same is with `Show entries`. What would be a clever way to deal with this issue?

[image: Table data]

Comment: On page change you have to fire that event again, for make that happen. or either place this function on the load event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using delegated events:

```
$("#table_id").on('change',"input[type='checkbox']",function(e){
    //your code 
});
```

This tells the table to run the specified function when a 'change' event originated from an `input[type='checkbox']` that is its descendant.

You don't need to register this handler in the table initialization by the way, you can just do it after the document is ready.

[More about delegated events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1):

You can place your code here `.on( 'page.dt',   function () { // do something})` check [the link](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html) for more explanation about this or you could place this event around with below code.

```
$(function(){$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {

            // checking if any checkbox is checked

      });})
```